# use nftables to open wlan0 and limit eth0 to out only

Tags: nftables

I'm using Raspberry Pi3+ (Buster 6.1) as MQTT broker on wlan0 (AP serving dhcp to IOT) and using eth0 (gets dhcp from house router) to get NTP and send notifications through Gmail.  It all works, now for rookie security, I'd like to leave wifi open to ports 5900 and 8883 on wlan0 but deny access from The Web on eth0. Any searches I find show how to bridge the two interfaces which is totally backward for me.
Since NFTables seems new, as am I, let's use that. I'm thinking use something like:

```
# nft list ruleset
table inet filter {
    chain input {
        type filter hook input priority 0; policy drop;
```

Looking at several sites, the syntax has me all balled up.  Does the above permit output and disable input? If so, how do I specify eth0?
As for wlan0 I figure I'll use VNC not ssh. Therefore can I limit wlan0 to ports 8883 (MQTT) and 5900 (VCN).
It all sounds pretty simple to me, but I just can't wrap my head around NFT syntax. Any help is appreciated (including recommended tags like sub for non-bridged).